# Getting error while calling new activity from onPostExecute

Tags: android

Getting error as below

> 08-14 19:43:41.828: D/AndroidRuntime(31363): Shutting down VM 08-14
>   19:43:41.833: E/AndroidRuntime(31363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-14
>   19:43:41.833: E/AndroidRuntime(31363): Process: com.example.ecmglogin,
>   PID: 31363 08-14 19:43:41.833: E/AndroidRuntime(31363):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference 08-14 19:43:41.833: E/AndroidRuntime(31363):    at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:107)

Submitdata.java

```
public class Submitdata extends Activity{   

    public Submitdata() {
        super();
    }   


    public void m1(){
        new TestAsync().execute(issuem);    
    }


    public class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<IssueParametersModel, String, JSONObject>{

        private ProgressDialog nDialog;     
        Context context;



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {     
            super.onPreExecute();               
        }       

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Datavalues... params) {


        //....
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){                     

                        Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
                        upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                     
                        startActivity(upanel);                      
                        finish();

                    }else{
                        nDialog.setMessage("Error");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {             
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }   

}
```

SubmitIssueCompleted.java

```
package com.example.ecmglogin;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SubmitIssueCompleted extends Activity {    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);
    }

}
```

newlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting error at this line

```
Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
```

Comment: Where are you running `m1` from?

Comment: I assume you did `new Submitdata()` somewhere and called that `m1()` method on it. Don't do that. Your Context is null, and your app crashed

Comment: [Avoid using inner class AsynTasks](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/117/asynctask/5377/possible-problems-with-inner-async-tasks#t=20160814173348633377).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
Intent upanel = new Intent(Submitdata.this, NewActivity.class);
upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                     
startActivity(upanel);                      
finish();
```

This will solve you problem.